# Cannot delete this file

Tags: terminal, finder, trash

I have a file in the trash can. I would like to delete it.

- Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
- System Version: macOS 10.14 (18A391)

Here's what my trash looks like:

[image]

Here's the info for the file:

[[image: 2]]

Here's what happens when I try to delete it normally:

[image]

Here's what happens when I try to delete the file immediately by right clicking:

[image]

Here's what I tried in terminal:

[image]

Please help me delete this piece of garbage.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have an issue with the app itself, but rather with the `AutomatorApplet.icns`? Try moving that one file from `/Users/jackson/.Trash/Untitled 24.app/Contents/Resources/` to somewhere else, and try deleting the app again.

Comment: Did you reboot your system already?

Comment: @Buscar That's just one instance of the icon. The path given to AutomatorApplet.icns is correct for an Automator (workflow exported as an) application.

Comment: @Buscar웃 so I'm curious, how would I find out what the app does?

Comment: @Ambidextrous I'm sorry, move the file in the trash, or the AutomatorApplet.icns?

Comment: @nohillside Yes

Comment: @grg as you say just one instance, user created, so why is it refusing to delete it ?

Comment: did you try `rm -rf`?